# FDW in Postgres: Batching ids for an external request?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper, multicorn

I'm developing a collection of foreign data wrappers using [multicorn](http://multicorn.org/) and I've run into an issue with batching data.

So, I have two foreign tables, `search` and `data`, that are each backed by a foreign data wrapper that I'm writing.

I need to do a basic join on these tables:

```
SELECT data.*
FROM search, data
WHERE search.data_id = data.id
AND search.term = 'search for this pls'
```

This works, but there's a hitch in the `data` fdw being able to batch queries to the server.  If the `search` table returns 5 ids for a given search, then the `data` fdw is executed once for each of those ids.  The API backing the `data` fdw is capable of processing many ids in one request.

The following works:

```
SELECT data.*
FROM data
WHERE id in ('2244', '31895')
```

In this case the `data` fdw receives an array of both ids and is able to perform one request.

Is there any way to make the join work where the `data` fdw has the opportunity to batch ids for a request?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your PostgreSQL version?

Comment: 9.6.2, using the postgres 9.6 docker container

Comment: `search` and `data` are foreign tables, not the FDWs themselves. I'm not sure I fully understand: are you developing some actual FDW(s) (and want write them to perform better) or just using some (and want to fine-tune your queries)?

Comment: I'm writing fdws using multicorn.  The fdws are making requests to an external webserver to retrieve data and I'd like to take advantage of batching those requests in some way.  For this example, each fdw has one foreign table, `data`, and `search`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the `EXPLAIN` output for your query, and then you'll probably see that PostgreSQL is performing a *nested loop join*, i.e. it scans `search` for the matching rows, and for each result row scans `data` for matching rows.

PostgreSQL has other join strategies like *hash joins*, but for that it would have to read the *whole* `data` table, which is probably not a win.
You might want to try it by setting `enable_nestloop`to `off` and testing query performance. If that is an improvement, you might want to adjust the cost values for the foreign table scan on `data` to reflect the high “startup costs” so that the planner becomes more reluctant to choose a nested loop join.

There is no such join strategy as you propose – while it may well be a win for FDW joins, it does not offer advantages in regular joins. So if the join strategy you envision is really the optimal one, you'd have to first fetch the `data_id`s from `search`, construct a query for `data` and implement the join in the application.

Comment: Thanks!  It definitely is using a nested loop, which I had adjusted the costs to get it to do to avoid the "read the whole table" thing, which unfortunately doesn't work for this case.  It's good to know there isn't a join strategy like that (and it's easy to see why it wouldn't make sense for other cases).